# How to get discord bot to create an admin role and assign it to me on command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that will create an admin role with administrator permissions with an admin command.

I've  tried this code complied from other sources, but I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```js
        let member = await server.fetch_member(message.author.id);

        await message.guild.createRole({name:"admin", color: "00FFFF", permissions: "ADMINISTRATOR",});
        await member.add_roles(role="admin", reason="role added");
        

        await message.channel.send('success');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which sources you looked at. Check the [Discord.JS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome) Documentation.

I used [RoleManager.create()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) to supply a `name` aswell as a `Administrator` permission via `PermissionFlagBits`. This will return a promise.  I will await the promise and assign the role.

Lastly, I will use [GuildMemberRoleManager.add()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) to add the new role.

I wrapped my code in a try/catch block to catch any Discord API errors.

```js
import { PermissionFlagsBits } from "discord.js";
// or const { PermissionFlagsBits } = require("discord.js");
// depending on your environment

// ...

try {
   const newAdminRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
      name: "Admin",
      permissions: [PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator]
   });

   await message.member.roles.add(newAdminRole);
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```